# Unable to find Accuracy and the ROC curve of my CNN model

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, evaluation, roc

My sample CNN code looks below:

```
classifier = Sequential()
#1st Conv layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, (9, 9), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4)))
#2nd Conv layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.1))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/png_orig_imgs/Training',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/png_orig_imgs/Test',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical'
                                           )
probs=classifier.fit(x = training_set, validation_data = test_set, epochs = 50)
```

I tried the following line to find the ROC curve, but i get an error message:

```
predictions = classifier.predict(test_set)
fpr, tpr,threshold = roc_curve(test_set,predictions)
```

The following error message is displayed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-2ea53b1ba7f1> in <module>
----> 1 fpr, tpr,threshold = roc_curve(test_set,predictions)

ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got <keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x000002D21D1B61C0>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: hy! @farabee will you please share any collab notebook? So I can see what is the problem with the code.

Comment: Do tell me the type of y_test and predictions by typing type(y_test)

Answer (score 0):

Emm! From the error, I think you have to change keras.processing image object to array. Try this I think this will help you out.

Accuracy

```
fil_acc_orig = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions.to_array())
```

ROC Curve

```
fil_acc_orig = roc_curve(y_test, predictions.to_array())
```

Comment: Hi @sohaib,
I tried the above code. But I get the following error.

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-b85cd33617bd> in <module>
----> 1 fil_acc_orig = accuracy_score(predictions, predictions.to_array())

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_array'

Comment: okay, what is the type of prediction and Y_test?

Comment: I actually didn't use x_train, y-train, x_test and y_test. I saved my images into my training and test set folder and used it as mentioned in my above code. is there a way that I can find the ROC using the above method or should I need to split it into training and test set.

Comment: No No! I i just need to know that which type of variables are you sending to ROC function like in this '''roc_curve(y_test, predictions.to_array()) ''' what is type of y-test and what is type of predictions

Comment: Type of Y_test and predictions is numpy.ndarray

Comment: But this error refers that :ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got <keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x000002D21D1B61C0> you are passing keras.processing.image object